# /usr/bin/node no such file or directory

Tags: centos, software-installation, node.js

I currently broke my node setup by attempting to upgrade it following a tutorial.  I added a symlink and I was told to just reinstall node on here since the symlink can't be undone.

I went ahead and did that by following yet another tutorial.
Ran this:

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
yum install nodejs
```

I got a bunch of these with the ending Error Summary:

```
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number from install of nodejs-2:6.17.1-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which from install of nodejs-2:6.17.1-1nodesource.x86_64 conflicts with file from package npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch

Error Summary
-------------
```

I then ran `node -v`
The error I get is:

```
bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

I checked and this is there but "node" appears black with the type pink like so:
[image]

Any idea how I can get node back up?

Comment: Please would you [add links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/524300/edit) to these "tutorials" you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "tutorials" are a calamity.

I'm not administering centos machines, but on my centos **7** vm test machine (yours looks like centos 6), this is how I installed `nodejs`:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install nodejs
```

A (completely untested) method to fix the damage would be to remove the `nodejs` package, remove the `nodesource` repository, and then install `nodejs` from epel:

```
yum remove nodejs
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource*
yum install epel-release
yum install nodejs
```